# Check if list as value(with atleast one element) exists in dictionary and return it

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a following dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'Diacto Group': {'id': 7547,
                  'type': 'user',
                  'name': 'Diacto Group',
                  'filters': [{'column': 'Core Area',
                  'values': ['Missiles & Aviation Technology'],
                  'operator': 'EQUALS',
                  'not': False}],
                  'users': [],
                  'virtualUsers': [],
                  'groups': [360305499]},
 'Diacto People': {'id': 7548,
                   'type': 'user',
                   'name': 'Diacto People',
                   'filters': [{'column': 'Core Area',
                   'values': ['Aircraft Company', 'Aviation Technology'],
                   'operator': 'EQUALS',
                   'not': False}],
                   'users': [326197441, 1293859642],
                   'virtualUsers': [],
                   'groups': []},
}
```

Basically I want to extract either one of the lists from *'users'* or *'groups'* if they have list containing atleast one value. I want the final output to look like this:

```
l1 = [# Extracted list as value from 'group' key from Diacto Group key as users key was blank 
      # list.
      [360305499],                
      # Extracted list as value from 'users' key from Diacto People key as groups key was 
      # blank list.
      [326197441, 1293859642]
     ]
```

List comprehension would be more preferable if possible.
Thank you for the efforts and time you put into this.

Comment: is it guaranteed that is either `users` or `groups` is populated that the other is empty?

Comment: Please post the code you tried and shortly explain where your problem lies.

Comment: @gold_cy yes either of the both are is guaranteed to be empty, but do consider the possibility that both are not empty to make your answer more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest I can think of with comprehension, provided either 'users' or 'groups' is not empty:

```
[v['users']+v['groups'] for v in dict1.values()]
```

Comment: @Aztec-3x5 - Note that your output will have empty lists if both "users" and "groups" is empty. You need an `if` condition to filter those out.

Comment: @not_speshal is right. also both will be concatenated if not empty (you didn't specify the behavior in this case)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be possible to do with list comprehension, but extremely difficult to understand.

This would be my approach:

```py
l1 = []
for k in dict1:
    if len(dict1[k]['users']) > 0:
        l1.append(dict1[k]['users'])
    if len(dict1[k]['groups']) > 0:
        l1.append(dict1[k]['groups'])
print(l1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension and filtering out cases where both "users" and "groups" are empty:

```
l1 = [v["users"]+v["groups"] for _, v in dict1.items() if v["users"]+v["groups"]]
```